# Long to Object implicit converions broken?

Tags: c#, datetime, object, 64-bit

I have this code:

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Today;
long l = d.ToBinary();
object o = (long)l;
d = new DateTime((long)o);
```

When I execute this code, I get an error on `d = new Date..`(the last line). It says the argument is out of range; that it is out of the range of max and min ticks. Which does seem probable, as using a debugger `l` is a huge negative number(and I didn't think ticks could be negative).

Is C#'s `object/long` broken or am I just missing something here? I've also tried setting the `DateTimeKind` and that did nothing.

Also, this work is being done on a 64 bit machine.(though that shouldn't matter due to .NET)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Today;
long l = d.ToBinary();
object o = (long)l;
d = DateTime.FromBinary((long)o);
```

Notice that I am using the [`DateTime.FromBinary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.frombinary.aspx) method:

> Deserializes a 64-bit binary value and recreates an original serialized DateTime object.

The constructor you were calling before was expecting ticks as opposed to the serialized form of `DateTime`.

Answer (score 3):

Who says that ToBinary() gets Ticks?

I assume it should look like this:

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Today;
long l = d.Ticks;
object o = l;
d = new DateTime((long)o);
```

Comment: I thought that ToBinary got ticks.. I wasn't aware there was a distinction.. ugh... (goes and fixes quite a few lines of code)

Comment: No, ToBinary includes the DateTime.Kind property (two bits) and the DateTime.Ticks property (sixty-two bits).

Comment: @earlz: The value returned by `ToBinary` also incorporates the `DateTimeKind` in the high bits. (Hence the huge negative number you mentioned in the question.)

Answer (score 0):

You should be using [`DateTime.FromBinary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.frombinary.aspx) to reconstitute a `DateTime` from a `long` binary representation obtained using `DateTime.ToBinary`.

A few other comments:

1. The conversion from a `long` to an `object` that you have in your code is an explicit conversion, not an implicit one.
2. It's strange that your suspicion would be that such a conversion is broken. Without doubt, that is an operation that is been battlefield tested at least a million times since the appearance of .NET.
3. If you use the debugger (or `Console.WriteLine` statements) you could have seen that `l` and `o` represent the same `long` value. This would suggest to you that it is not the conversion that is broken, but something else.
4. MSDN can be extremely helpful for answering questions like this one. Once you realized that `l` was very negative, your suspicion should have been that [`DateTime.ToBinary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tobinary.aspx) does not represent only `DateTime.Ticks`. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tobinary.aspx) confirms this.